# How can I delete my undefined indexes in the array and move the others to position 0?

Tags: php, arrays, unset, undefined-index

I'm having an array I'm unsetting.

In my example, I'm unsetting the first object in the array.

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 )

unset(Array[0]);
```

It gives me back:

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 )
```

Index 0 is gone. How can I make the array start from index 0 that I would get this back?

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_values()` to reindex the array:

```
unset($array[0]);
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the first element, you can use array_shift to remove it. Remaining numbers are automatically shuffled down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array = your array
array_shift($array);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```